# how to not pass through the split 2 times

Tags: java, java-stream

Output a sentence of the text in ascending order of words. I did so but how to not pass through the array 2 times, I do split twice or maybe somehow at once do

```
     Arrays.stream(s1.split("[.!?]+ *"))
.sorted(Comparator.comparing( s -> s.split(" ").length))
.collect(Collectors.joining("."))
```

Comment: What do you mean with “pass through the array 2 times”? Which array? The array returned by `s1.split("[.!?]+ *")` is an entirely different array than any array returned by `s.split(" ")`. The latter operation may be performed far more often than two times. And `s.split(" ").length` is a very inefficient way to count the number of spaces anyway.

Comment: I need to sort the sentence by the number of words, that's looking for the best way, but I do not want to use 2 times split

Comment: “best way” in what regard? There are many different metrics. You can replace `s.split(" ").length` by a plain loop counting the space characters.

Comment: but I would do it in stream and not in loop

Comment: Since the expression `s.split(" ").length` has nothing to do with streams, replacing it with a for loop has nothing to do with streams either. It’s just a detail of the function you use to construct the comparator. But well, you can also use another, unrelated stream operation to substitute that for loop, i.e. `Comparator.comparingLong(s -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == ' ').count())`

Answer (score 1):

You said print out the text in ascending order of words.

I believe this is what you want to do.

- `[.!?\\s]+` - a character class that splits on any combination of punctuation including spaces.
- then just sort the array and join the words however required.

```
String s1 = "Is is time to start writing code?";
String str = Arrays.stream(s1.split("[.!?\\s]+"))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("."));

System.out.println(str);
```

prints

```
code.Is.it.start.time.to.writing
```

If you want to sort based on ascending lengths of the words, then do it like this.

```
String str = Arrays.stream(s1.split("[.!?\\s]+"))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("."));

System.out.println(str);
```

prints

```
Is.it.to.time.code.start.writing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the sentence by word like below

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String input = "I want to sort the sentence";
        final String output = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(it -> it.chars().count()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("."));

        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

**Output**

`I.to.the.want.sort.sentence`